# Tile inside Accordion does not resize correctly

Tags: flex3, resize, accordion, tile

In a Flex application I'm building I have an Accordion with a Tile component as shown:

```
<mx:Accordion id="accordionShoppingBasket" width="100%" resizeToContent="true">
    <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%" >
        <mx:Tile id="tileOutNow" width="100%" height="100%" horizontalGap="12" verticalGap="30" paddingLeft="20" paddingRight="20" paddingBottom="20" paddingTop="20" verticalScrollPolicy="off" />                                     
    </mx:VBox>
    <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:Tile id="tileThisWeek" width="100%" height="100%" horizontalGap="12" verticalGap="30" paddingLeft="20" paddingRight="20" paddingBottom="20" paddingTop="20"/>
    </mx:VBox>
    <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:Tile id="tileFutureRelease" width="100%" height="100%" horizontalGap="12" verticalGap="30" paddingLeft="20" paddingRight="20" paddingBottom="20" paddingTop="20"/>
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:Accordion>
```

The items I'm adding to the tiles are a canvas with an image inside that.

The data for the tile is added via the addChild method; and this works for the first 4 rows of children, the accordion control resizes to accommodate the tile control. After the first 4 rows the children are still being added but the accordion no longer resizes to fit the content.

I'm not 100% sure what's causing this, any ideas?

Cheers
Tony

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, you want the Accordion resize to its content, BUT, you set the content size to 100% ... its look like an endless loop ...

Try removing the resizeToContent OR set a correct size for the children Tile(s) ...

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, what do the parent(s) of the accordion look like? Meaning, could their height be restricting the height of the accordion?

Otherwise, posting more code might be necessary.

Comment: The parent is a a canvas which the height is set to 100%.